# Weird spikes in MySQL query times

Tags: mysql, performance, spike

I'm running a NodeJS with MySQL (InnoDB) for a game server (player info, savedata, stuff). Server is HTTP(S) based so nothing realtime.

I'm having these weird spikes as you can see from the graphs below (first graph is requests/sec and last graph is queries/sec)

On the response time graph you can see max response times with purple and avg response times with blue. Even with those 10-20k peaks avg stays at 50-100ms as do 95% of the requests.

I've been digging around and found that the slow queries are nothing special. Usually update query with savedata (blob of ~2kb) or player profile update which modifies like username or so. No joins or anything like that. We're talking about tables with less than 100k rows.

Server is running in Azure on Ubuntu 14.04 with MySQL 5.7 using 4 cores and 7GB of RAM.

[image: Server monitor stuff]

MySQL settings:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
query_cache_type=0
tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=64M
sort_buffer_size=32M
wait_timeout=300
interactive_timeout=300
innodb_file_per_table=ON
```

Edit: It turned out that the problem was never MySQL performance but Node.js performance before the SQL queries. More info here: [Node.js multer and body-parser sometimes extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321252/node-js-multer-and-body-parser-sometimes-extremely-slow)

Comment: Can you check the disk throughput as well? Sometimes disk also can be busy and that may cause to spikes. Also if this is write heavy system there can be lots of things happening in the background like lock waits, deadlocks etc. Those also can results to this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Nothing strange happening on IO side. The server is not running much else than the backend.

Comment: are there any hourly cronjobs using up resources, it looks like they are on fixed intervals? Maybe logrotation or something

Comment: 20Kms for response time, yet nothing useful in the slowlog??  Crank `long_query_time` down to 1 or 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

check your swappiness (suppose to be 0 mysql machines maximizing ram usage):

```
> sysctl -A|grep swap
vm.swappiness = 0
```

with only 7G of RAM and 4G of just buffer pool, your machine will swap if swappiness is not zero.

could you post your swap graph and used memory. 4G buffer is "over the edge" for 7G ram. For 8G ram, I would give 3G as you have +1G on everything else mysql wise + 2G on OS.

Also you have 1G for transaction log file and I assume you have two log files. Do you have so many writes to have such large files? You can use this guide: https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/

Comment: It was set to 60, changed it to 0. Will see how it affects.

Comment: I started with default config and tried to optimize it using a lot of these guides. One said log should be 25% of the buffer size, so I went with 1G.

Comment: I have upgraded MySQL from 5.5 -> 5.7 and also upgraded the VM to slightly faster CPU's with 14GB RAM. I'm currently running the server with old conf (4G buffer even though double RAM). Swappiness is now 0 and "available memory" shows at 10G. We're expecting at least 100x more traffic in the near future and I'm panicking with this server.

Comment: You may as well crank up the buffer_pool to be 70% of RAM.

Comment: 100x -- Have you looked into replication and having Slaves take on the read load?